# Spring Boot Azure CosmosDB NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class com.azure.data.cosmos.internal.directconnectivity.rntbd.RntbdConstants

Tags: java, spring-boot, azure-cosmosdb, spring-cloud

I am trying to configure Azure CosmosDB in my Spring project, but I'm getting 
the following stack trace:

```
2020-03-28 13:02:09.192  INFO 19585 --- [           main] c.a.d.c.internal.RxDocumentClientImpl    : Initializing DocumentClient with serviceEndpoint [https://***.documents.azure.com:443/], connectionPolicy [ConnectionPolicy{requestTimeoutInMillis=60000, mediaRequestTimeoutInMillis=300000, connectionMode=DIRECT, maxPoolSize=1000, idleConnectionTimeoutInMillis=60000, userAgentSuffix=';spring-data/2.2.3;', retryOptions=RetryOptions{maxRetryAttemptsOnThrottledRequests=9, maxRetryWaitTimeInSeconds=30}, enableEndpointDiscovery=true, preferredLocations=null, usingMultipleWriteLocations=false, inetSocketProxyAddress=null}], consistencyLevel [null], directModeProtocol [Tcp]
2020-03-28 13:02:09.405  INFO 19585 --- [     parallel-1] c.a.d.c.internal.RxDocumentClientImpl    : Getting database account endpoint from https://***.documents.azure.com:443/
2020-03-28 13:02:12.881  WARN 19585 --- [s-rntbd-nio-2-4] c.a.d.c.i.d.r.RntbdClientChannelPool     : Channel([id: 0x1fd9aa13, L:/192.168.14.122:58535 - R:cdb-ms-prod-westus2-fd19.documents.azure.com/40.78.243.194:11004]) health check request failed due to:

java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class com.azure.data.cosmos.internal.directconnectivity.rntbd.RntbdConstants$RntbdContextRequestHeader
    at com.azure.data.cosmos.internal.directconnectivity.rntbd.RntbdContextRequest$Headers.<init>(RntbdContextRequest.java:126)
    at com.azure.data.cosmos.internal.directconnectivity.rntbd.RntbdContextRequest$Headers.<init>(RntbdContextRequest.java:118)
    at com.azure.data.cosmos.internal.directconnectivity.rntbd.RntbdContextRequest.<init>(RntbdContextRequest.java:33)
    at com.azure.data.cosmos.internal.directconnectivity.rntbd.RntbdContextNegotiator.startRntbdContextRequest(RntbdContextNegotiator.java:77)
    at com.azure.data.cosmos.internal.directconnectivity.rntbd.RntbdContextNegotiator.write(RntbdContextNegotiator.java:63)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeWrite0(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:717)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeWrite(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:709)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.write(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:792)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.write(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:702)
    at io.netty.handler.codec.MessageToByteEncoder.write(MessageToByteEncoder.java:120)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeWrite0(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:717)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeWrite(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:709)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.write(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:792)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.write(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:702)
    at com.azure.data.cosmos.internal.directconnectivity.rntbd.RntbdRequestManager.write(RntbdRequestManager.java:502)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeWrite0(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:717)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeWriteAndFlush(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:764)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.write(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:790)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.writeAndFlush(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:758)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.writeAndFlush(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:808)
    at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.writeAndFlush(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:1025)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannel.writeAndFlush(AbstractChannel.java:294)
    at com.azure.data.cosmos.internal.directconnectivity.rntbd.RntbdClientChannelPool$AcquireListener.lambda$operationComplete$1(RntbdClientChannelPool.java:561)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.AbstractEventExecutor.safeExecute(AbstractEventExecutor.java:164)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor.runAllTasks(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:472)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:497)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$4.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:989)
    at io.netty.util.internal.ThreadExecutorMap$2.run(ThreadExecutorMap.java:74)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.FastThreadLocalRunnable.run(FastThreadLocalRunnable.java:30)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
```

The class `com.azure.data.cosmos.internal.directconnectivity.rntbd.RntbdConstants$RntbdContextRequestHeader` comes from `com.microsoft.azure:azure-cosmos:jar:3.7.1` which I have in my dependencies:

```
  --- maven-dependency-plugin:2.8:tree (default-cli) @ my-service ---
 com.avpines.poc:my-service:jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
 +- org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-starter-kubernetes:jar:1.1.2.RELEASE:compile
 |  +- org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-kubernetes-core:jar:1.1.2.RELEASE:compile
 |  |  +- io.fabric8:kubernetes-client:jar:4.4.1:compile
 |  |  |  +- io.fabric8:kubernetes-model:jar:4.4.1:compile
 |  |  |  |  +- io.fabric8:kubernetes-model-common:jar:4.4.1:compile
 |  |  |  |  +- com.fasterxml.jackson.module:jackson-module-jaxb-annotations:jar:2.10.3:compile
 |  |  |  |  +- javax.validation:validation-api:jar:2.0.1.Final:compile
 |  |  |  |  +- org.glassfish:javax.el:jar:3.0.1-b11:compile
 |  |  |  |  +- javax.annotation:javax.annotation-api:jar:1.3.2:compile
 |  |  |  |  \- javax.xml.bind:jaxb-api:jar:2.3.1:compile
 |  |  |  |     \- javax.activation:javax.activation-api:jar:1.2.0:compile
 |  |  |  +- com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:jar:3.12.0:compile
 |  |  |  |  \- com.squareup.okio:okio:jar:1.15.0:compile
 |  |  |  +- com.squareup.okhttp3:logging-interceptor:jar:3.12.0:compile
 |  |  |  +- org.slf4j:jul-to-slf4j:jar:1.7.30:compile
 |  |  |  +- com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat:jackson-dataformat-yaml:jar:2.10.3:compile
 |  |  |  +- io.fabric8:zjsonpatch:jar:0.3.0:compile
 |  |  |  \- com.github.mifmif:generex:jar:1.0.2:compile
 |  |  |     \- dk.brics.automaton:automaton:jar:1.11-8:compile
 |  |  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-autoconfigure:jar:2.2.6.RELEASE:compile
 |  |  \- org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-context:jar:2.2.2.RELEASE:compile
 |  |     \- org.springframework.security:spring-security-crypto:jar:5.2.2.RELEASE:compile
 |  \- org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-kubernetes-discovery:jar:1.1.2.RELEASE:compile
 |     \- org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-commons:jar:2.2.2.RELEASE:compile
 +- org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-starter-kubernetes-config:jar:1.1.2.RELEASE:compile
 |  \- org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-kubernetes-config:jar:1.1.2.RELEASE:compile
 |     \- org.springframework.security:spring-security-rsa:jar:1.0.9.RELEASE:compile
 |        \- org.bouncycastle:bcpkix-jdk15on:jar:1.64:compile
 |           \- org.bouncycastle:bcprov-jdk15on:jar:1.64:compile
 +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web:jar:2.2.6.RELEASE:compile
 |  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter:jar:2.2.6.RELEASE:compile
 |  |  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot:jar:2.2.6.RELEASE:compile
 |  |  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-logging:jar:2.2.6.RELEASE:compile
 |  |  |  \- org.apache.logging.log4j:log4j-to-slf4j:jar:2.12.1:compile
 |  |  |     \- org.apache.logging.log4j:log4j-api:jar:2.12.1:compile
 |  |  +- jakarta.annotation:jakarta.annotation-api:jar:1.3.5:compile
 |  |  \- org.yaml:snakeyaml:jar:1.25:compile
 |  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-json:jar:2.2.6.RELEASE:compile
 |  |  \- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind:jar:2.10.3:compile
 |  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-tomcat:jar:2.2.6.RELEASE:compile
 |  |  +- org.apache.tomcat.embed:tomcat-embed-core:jar:9.0.33:compile
 |  |  +- org.apache.tomcat.embed:tomcat-embed-el:jar:9.0.33:compile
 |  |  \- org.apache.tomcat.embed:tomcat-embed-websocket:jar:9.0.33:compile
 |  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-validation:jar:2.2.6.RELEASE:compile
 |  |  +- jakarta.validation:jakarta.validation-api:jar:2.0.2:compile
 |  |  \- org.hibernate.validator:hibernate-validator:jar:6.0.18.Final:compile
 |  |     +- org.jboss.logging:jboss-logging:jar:3.4.1.Final:compile
 |  |     \- com.fasterxml:classmate:jar:1.5.1:compile
 |  +- org.springframework:spring-web:jar:5.2.5.RELEASE:compile
 |  \- org.springframework:spring-webmvc:jar:5.2.5.RELEASE:compile
 +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-actuator:jar:2.2.6.RELEASE:compile
 |  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-actuator-autoconfigure:jar:2.2.6.RELEASE:compile
 |  |  \- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-actuator:jar:2.2.6.RELEASE:compile
 |  \- io.micrometer:micrometer-core:jar:1.3.6:compile
 |     +- org.hdrhistogram:HdrHistogram:jar:2.1.11:compile
 |     \- org.latencyutils:LatencyUtils:jar:2.0.3:compile
 +- org.projectlombok:lombok:jar:1.18.12:compile
 +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-configuration-processor:jar:2.2.6.RELEASE:compile
 +- org.jetbrains:annotations:jar:16.0.2:compile
 +- com.devskiller.friendly-id:friendly-id:jar:1.1.0:compile
 +- com.microsoft.azure:azure-cosmosdb-spring-boot-starter:jar:2.2.3:compile
 |  \- com.microsoft.azure:azure-spring-boot:jar:2.2.3:compile
 |     +- com.azure:azure-security-keyvault-secrets:jar:4.1.0:compile
 |     |  +- com.azure:azure-core:jar:1.2.0:compile
 |     |  |  +- com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat:jackson-dataformat-xml:jar:2.10.3:compile
 |     |  |  |  +- org.codehaus.woodstox:stax2-api:jar:4.2:compile
 |     |  |  |  \- com.fasterxml.woodstox:woodstox-core:jar:6.1.1:compile
 |     |  |  \- io.netty:netty-tcnative-boringssl-static:jar:2.0.30.Final:compile
 |     |  \- com.azure:azure-core-http-netty:jar:1.2.0:compile
 |     |     \- io.netty:netty-transport-native-unix-common:jar:4.1.48.Final:compile
 |     \- com.azure:azure-identity:jar:1.0.2:compile
 |        +- com.microsoft.azure:msal4j:jar:0.5.0-preview:compile
 |        |  +- com.google.code.gson:gson:jar:2.8.6:compile
 |        |  +- commons-codec:commons-codec:jar:1.13:compile
 |        |  \- org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient:jar:4.5.12:compile
 |        |     \- org.apache.httpcomponents:httpcore:jar:4.4.13:compile
 |        +- com.nimbusds:oauth2-oidc-sdk:jar:6.14:compile
 |        |  +- com.sun.mail:javax.mail:jar:1.6.1:compile
 |        |  |  \- javax.activation:activation:jar:1.1:compile
 |        |  +- com.github.stephenc.jcip:jcip-annotations:jar:1.0-1:compile
 |        |  +- com.nimbusds:lang-tag:jar:1.4.4:compile (version selected from constraint [1.4.3,))
 |        |  \- com.nimbusds:nimbus-jose-jwt:jar:8.11:compile (version selected from constraint [6.0.1,))
 |        +- org.nanohttpd:nanohttpd:jar:2.3.1:compile
 |        \- net.java.dev.jna:jna-platform:jar:4.5.2:compile
 |           \- net.java.dev.jna:jna:jar:4.5.2:compile
 +- com.microsoft.azure:spring-data-cosmosdb:jar:2.2.3.FIX1:compile
 |  +- org.springframework:spring-core:jar:5.2.5.RELEASE:compile
 |  |  \- org.springframework:spring-jcl:jar:5.2.5.RELEASE:compile
 |  +- org.springframework:spring-beans:jar:5.2.5.RELEASE:compile
 |  +- org.springframework:spring-context:jar:5.2.5.RELEASE:compile
 |  +- org.springframework:spring-tx:jar:5.2.5.RELEASE:compile
 |  +- org.springframework.data:spring-data-commons:jar:2.2.6.RELEASE:compile
 |  +- org.springframework:spring-expression:jar:5.2.5.RELEASE:compile
 |  +- com.microsoft.azure:azure-cosmos:jar:3.7.1:compile           <-------- HERE
 |  |  +- com.fasterxml.uuid:java-uuid-generator:jar:3.2.0:compile
 |  |  +- commons-io:commons-io:jar:2.5:compile
 |  |  +- commons-validator:commons-validator:jar:1.6:compile
 |  |  |  +- commons-digester:commons-digester:jar:1.8.1:compile
 |  |  |  +- commons-logging:commons-logging:jar:1.2:compile
 |  |  |  \- commons-collections:commons-collections:jar:3.2.2:compile
 |  |  +- io.projectreactor:reactor-core:jar:3.3.4.RELEASE:compile
 |  |  |  \- org.reactivestreams:reactive-streams:jar:1.0.3:compile
 |  |  +- io.netty:netty-codec-http:jar:4.1.48.Final:compile
 |  |  |  +- io.netty:netty-common:jar:4.1.48.Final:compile
 |  |  |  +- io.netty:netty-buffer:jar:4.1.48.Final:compile
 |  |  |  +- io.netty:netty-transport:jar:4.1.48.Final:compile
 |  |  |  \- io.netty:netty-codec:jar:4.1.48.Final:compile
 |  |  +- io.netty:netty-handler:jar:4.1.48.Final:compile
 |  |  |  \- io.netty:netty-resolver:jar:4.1.48.Final:compile
 |  |  +- org.apache.commons:commons-lang3:jar:3.9:compile
 |  |  +- org.apache.commons:commons-collections4:jar:4.2:compile
 |  |  +- org.apache.commons:commons-text:jar:1.6:compile
 |  |  +- com.google.guava:guava:jar:28.2-android:compile
 |  |  |  +- com.google.guava:failureaccess:jar:1.0.1:compile
 |  |  |  +- com.google.guava:listenablefuture:jar:9999.0-empty-to-avoid-conflict-with-guava:compile
 |  |  |  +- com.google.code.findbugs:jsr305:jar:3.0.2:compile
 |  |  |  +- org.checkerframework:checker-compat-qual:jar:2.5.5:compile
 |  |  |  +- com.google.errorprone:error_prone_annotations:jar:2.3.4:compile
 |  |  |  \- com.google.j2objc:j2objc-annotations:jar:1.3:compile
 |  |  +- io.dropwizard.metrics:metrics-core:jar:4.1.5:compile
 |  |  +- io.reactivex.rxjava2:rxjava:jar:2.2.19:compile
 |  |  \- io.projectreactor.netty:reactor-netty:jar:0.9.6.RELEASE:compile
 |  |     +- io.netty:netty-codec-http2:jar:4.1.48.Final:compile
 |  |     +- io.netty:netty-handler-proxy:jar:4.1.48.Final:compile
 |  |     |  \- io.netty:netty-codec-socks:jar:4.1.48.Final:compile
 |  |     \- io.netty:netty-transport-native-epoll:jar:linux-x86_64:4.1.48.Final:compile
 |  +- com.fasterxml.jackson.module:jackson-module-parameter-names:jar:2.10.3:compile
 |  |  \- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-core:jar:2.10.3:compile
 |  +- com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype:jackson-datatype-jdk8:jar:2.10.3:compile
 |  +- com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype:jackson-datatype-jsr310:jar:2.10.3:compile
 |  |  \- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-annotations:jar:2.10.3:compile
 |  +- org.json:json:jar:20140107:compile
 |  \- org.javatuples:javatuples:jar:1.2:compile
 +- io.github.resilience4j:resilience4j-spring-cloud2:jar:1.3.1:compile
 |  +- io.vavr:vavr:jar:0.10.2:compile
 |  |  \- io.vavr:vavr-match:jar:0.10.2:compile
 |  +- org.slf4j:slf4j-api:jar:1.7.30:compile
 |  +- io.github.resilience4j:resilience4j-spring-cloud-common:jar:1.3.1:compile
 |  |  \- io.github.resilience4j:resilience4j-spring:jar:1.3.1:compile
 |  |     +- io.github.resilience4j:resilience4j-annotations:jar:1.3.1:compile
 |  |     +- io.github.resilience4j:resilience4j-consumer:jar:1.3.1:compile
 |  |     |  \- io.github.resilience4j:resilience4j-circularbuffer:jar:1.3.1:compile
 |  |     \- io.github.resilience4j:resilience4j-framework-common:jar:1.3.1:compile
 |  |        +- io.github.resilience4j:resilience4j-ratelimiter:jar:1.3.1:compile
 |  |        +- io.github.resilience4j:resilience4j-retry:jar:1.3.1:compile
 |  |        \- io.github.resilience4j:resilience4j-bulkhead:jar:1.3.1:compile
 |  \- io.github.resilience4j:resilience4j-spring-boot2:jar:1.3.1:compile
 |     \- io.github.resilience4j:resilience4j-spring-boot-common:jar:1.3.1:compile
 +- io.github.resilience4j:resilience4j-circuitbreaker:jar:1.3.1:compile
 |  \- io.github.resilience4j:resilience4j-core:jar:1.3.1:compile
 +- io.github.resilience4j:resilience4j-timelimiter:jar:1.3.1:compile
 +- io.github.resilience4j:resilience4j-micrometer:jar:1.3.1:compile
 +- io.github.resilience4j:resilience4j-reactor:jar:1.3.1:compile
 +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-aop:jar:2.2.6.RELEASE:compile
 |  +- org.springframework:spring-aop:jar:5.2.5.RELEASE:compile
 |  \- org.aspectj:aspectjweaver:jar:1.9.5:compile
 +- de.codecentric:chaos-monkey-spring-boot:jar:2.2.0:compile
 |  +- org.springframework:spring-aspects:jar:5.2.5.RELEASE:compile
 |  \- org.springframework:spring-instrument:jar:5.2.5.RELEASE:compile
 +- com.microsoft.azure:applicationinsights-logging-logback:jar:2.5.1:compile
 |  +- com.microsoft.azure:applicationinsights-core:jar:2.5.1:compile
 |  +- ch.qos.logback:logback-classic:jar:1.2.3:compile
 |  \- ch.qos.logback:logback-core:jar:1.2.3:compile
 +- com.microsoft.azure:applicationinsights-spring-boot-starter:jar:2.5.1:compile
 |  \- com.microsoft.azure:applicationinsights-web:jar:2.5.1:compile
 \- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test:jar:2.2.6.RELEASE:test
    +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-test:jar:2.2.6.RELEASE:test
    +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-test-autoconfigure:jar:2.2.6.RELEASE:test
    +- com.jayway.jsonpath:json-path:jar:2.4.0:test
    |  \- net.minidev:json-smart:jar:2.3:compile
    |     \- net.minidev:accessors-smart:jar:1.2:compile
    |        \- org.ow2.asm:asm:jar:5.0.4:compile
    +- jakarta.xml.bind:jakarta.xml.bind-api:jar:2.3.3:compile
    |  \- jakarta.activation:jakarta.activation-api:jar:1.2.2:compile
    +- org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter:jar:5.5.2:test
    |  +- org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-api:jar:5.5.2:test
    |  |  +- org.apiguardian:apiguardian-api:jar:1.1.0:test
    |  |  +- org.opentest4j:opentest4j:jar:1.2.0:test
    |  |  \- org.junit.platform:junit-platform-commons:jar:1.5.2:test
    |  +- org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-params:jar:5.5.2:test
    |  \- org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-engine:jar:5.5.2:test
    |     \- org.junit.platform:junit-platform-engine:jar:1.5.2:test
    +- org.mockito:mockito-junit-jupiter:jar:3.1.0:test
    +- org.assertj:assertj-core:jar:3.13.2:test
    +- org.hamcrest:hamcrest:jar:2.1:test
    +- org.mockito:mockito-core:jar:3.1.0:test
    |  +- net.bytebuddy:byte-buddy:jar:1.10.8:test
    |  +- net.bytebuddy:byte-buddy-agent:jar:1.10.8:test
    |  \- org.objenesis:objenesis:jar:2.6:test
    +- org.skyscreamer:jsonassert:jar:1.5.0:test
    |  \- com.vaadin.external.google:android-json:jar:0.0.20131108.vaadin1:test
    +- org.springframework:spring-test:jar:5.2.5.RELEASE:test
    \- org.xmlunit:xmlunit-core:jar:2.6.4:test
```

My CosmosDB beans:

```java
@Repository
public interface RawMessageRepository
        extends CosmosRepository<RawMessage, String> {
}
```

```java
@Service
public class MessageAccess {

    private final RawMessageRepository repository;

    @Autowired
    public MessageAccessImpl(RawMessageRepository repository) {
        this.repository = repository;
    }

    public RawMessage save(@NotNull Message message) {
        return repository.save(RawMessage.from(message));
    }

}
```

```java
@Slf4j
@Service
public class CosmosSink implements Sink {

    private final MessageAccess access;

    @Autowired
    public CosmosSink(MessageAccess access) {
        this.access = access;
    }

    @Override
    public List<Message> sink(Message message) {
        access.save(message);
        LOG.info("SAVED MESSAGE: '{}'", message);
        return Collections.singletonList(message);
    }

}
```

Once I remove these classes from the ApplicationContext
the context loads (the application obviously fails because
the needed classes are not in the context)

```
2020-03-28 13:24:20.633  INFO 26138 --- [           main] o.s.s.concurrent.ThreadPoolTaskExecutor  : Initializing ExecutorService 'applicationTaskExecutor'
2020-03-28 13:24:21.235  INFO 26138 --- [           main] c.a.d.c.internal.RxDocumentClientImpl    : Initializing DocumentClient with serviceEndpoint [https://***.documents.azure.com:443/], connectionPolicy [ConnectionPolicy{requestTimeoutInMillis=60000, mediaRequestTimeoutInMillis=300000, connectionMode=DIRECT, maxPoolSize=1000, idleConnectionTimeoutInMillis=60000, userAgentSuffix=';spring-data/2.2.3;', retryOptions=RetryOptions{maxRetryAttemptsOnThrottledRequests=9, maxRetryWaitTimeInSeconds=30}, enableEndpointDiscovery=true, preferredLocations=null, usingMultipleWriteLocations=false, inetSocketProxyAddress=null}], consistencyLevel [null], directModeProtocol [Tcp]
2020-03-28 13:24:21.350  INFO 26138 --- [     parallel-1] c.a.d.c.internal.RxDocumentClientImpl    : Getting database account endpoint from https://***.documents.azure.com:443/
2020-03-28 13:24:23.365  INFO 26138 --- [           main] c.a.d.c.internal.RxDocumentClientImpl    : Initializing DocumentClient with serviceEndpoint [https://***.documents.azure.com:443/], connectionPolicy [ConnectionPolicy{requestTimeoutInMillis=60000, mediaRequestTimeoutInMillis=300000, connectionMode=DIRECT, maxPoolSize=1000, idleConnectionTimeoutInMillis=60000, userAgentSuffix=';spring-data/2.2.3;;spring-data/2.2.3;', retryOptions=RetryOptions{maxRetryAttemptsOnThrottledRequests=9, maxRetryWaitTimeInSeconds=30}, enableEndpointDiscovery=true, preferredLocations=null, usingMultipleWriteLocations=false, inetSocketProxyAddress=null}], consistencyLevel [null], directModeProtocol [Tcp]
2020-03-28 13:24:23.367  INFO 26138 --- [     parallel-2] c.a.d.c.internal.RxDocumentClientImpl    : Getting database account endpoint from https://***.documents.azure.com:443/
2020-03-28 13:24:24.541  INFO 26138 --- [           main] c.a.d.c.internal.RxDocumentClientImpl    : Initializing DocumentClient with serviceEndpoint [https://***.documents.azure.com:443/], connectionPolicy [ConnectionPolicy{requestTimeoutInMillis=60000, mediaRequestTimeoutInMillis=300000, connectionMode=DIRECT, maxPoolSize=1000, idleConnectionTimeoutInMillis=60000, userAgentSuffix=';spring-data/2.2.3;;spring-data/2.2.3;;spring-data/2.2.3;', retryOptions=RetryOptions{maxRetryAttemptsOnThrottledRequests=9, maxRetryWaitTimeInSeconds=30}, enableEndpointDiscovery=true, preferredLocations=null, usingMultipleWriteLocations=false, inetSocketProxyAddress=null}], consistencyLevel [null], directModeProtocol [Tcp]
2020-03-28 13:24:24.543  INFO 26138 --- [     parallel-3] c.a.d.c.internal.RxDocumentClientImpl    : Getting database account endpoint from https://***.documents.azure.com:443/
2020-03-28 13:24:25.636  INFO 26138 --- [           main] c.a.d.c.internal.RxDocumentClientImpl    : Initializing DocumentClient with serviceEndpoint [https://***.documents.azure.com:443/], connectionPolicy [ConnectionPolicy{requestTimeoutInMillis=60000, mediaRequestTimeoutInMillis=300000, connectionMode=DIRECT, maxPoolSize=1000, idleConnectionTimeoutInMillis=60000, userAgentSuffix=';spring-data/2.2.3;;spring-data/2.2.3;;spring-data/2.2.3;;spring-data/2.2.3;', retryOptions=RetryOptions{maxRetryAttemptsOnThrottledRequests=9, maxRetryWaitTimeInSeconds=30}, enableEndpointDiscovery=true, preferredLocations=null, usingMultipleWriteLocations=false, inetSocketProxyAddress=null}], consistencyLevel [null], directModeProtocol [Tcp]
2020-03-28 13:24:25.638  INFO 26138 --- [     parallel-4] c.a.d.c.internal.RxDocumentClientImpl    : Getting database account endpoint from https://***.documents.azure.com:443/
2020-03-28 13:24:28.633  INFO 26138 --- [           main] .r.EventBasedConfigurationChangeDetector : Added new Kubernetes watch: config-maps-watch
2020-03-28 13:24:28.634  INFO 26138 --- [           main] .r.EventBasedConfigurationChangeDetector : Kubernetes event-based configuration change detector activated
```

Any idea where is the conflict coming from and how to resolve it? Please let me 
know if any more information is needed.

Comment: I am seeing this in a slightly odd way.  The spring boot app appears to start ok, but now of the test that require the context will start the spring boot app.  Very odd.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I did a some googling and little research. I foud following:

1. The missing class `com.azure.data.cosmos.internal.directconnectivity.rntbd.RntbdConstants$RntbdContextRequestHeader` is a part of `azure-cosmosdb-direct`, pls see [pom.xml](https://github.com/Azure/azure-cosmosdb-java/blob/master/direct-impl/pom.xml), class is located [here](https://github.com/Azure/azure-cosmosdb-java/blob/master/direct-impl/src/main/java/com/microsoft/azure/cosmosdb/internal/directconnectivity/rntbd/RntbdConstants.java#L82).
2. `azure-cosmosdb-direct` is missing from your dependency list. I assume it's incomplete or hidden for some reason(?)
3. Looking at exception stacktrace it's clear that `at com.azure.data.cosmos.internal.directconnectivity.rntbd.RntbdContextRequest$Headers.<init>(RntbdContextRequest.java:126)` is a place where exceptiom occurs. So that means `RntbdContextRequest` class actually existsts (it's also is a part of `azure-cosmosdb-direct`). Therefore you have needed dependency, but it probably has wrong version.

I propose you to look a bit deeper into how `azure-cosmosdb-direct` dependency is injected in your project and fix its version. Just try to declare it directly in your `pom.xml` with the [latest](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.microsoft.azure/azure-cosmosdb-direct/2.6.6) version.

Hope I helped you.

Comment: Your Google-Fu is stronger than mine, that was it! After adding the dependency I had another issue with Guava, and after adding it to the `pom.xml` `com.google.guava:guava:28.2-jre` everything started to work. Thanks!